# Upload files directly to the FTP server by using "Jquery file upload plugin"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, host

I am using the "[Blueimp Jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)" on my website, and I give a permission to users to can uploading files on my sever. I hosted my website on HostGator.
The problem is that users cannot upload files' size more than 64MB/file, and after searching I found that HostGator has setting this limit of the uploading files to 64MB/file as a maximum in the "php.ini" file, and I cannot change this size limit.

But actually I can upload any size of files without any limits directly via the FTP.

So, am asking about if there is a workaround that I can use to avoid this HostGator Limits,
or if there is way to allow users uploading the files directly to the server via FTP throw this jquery plugin "web application".

Comment: No; you cannot use FTP from Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **definitely** can change hostgator's max file size settings, as I've done it before several times.

In the directory of your choosing, create a .htaccess file. In this file include php overwrite settings.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

Unless something has changed in the last few months, this workaround has always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but this solution doesn't work with me, I just added this code in a .htaccess file in the uploads folder directly"I don't know if that right or not", also I want to ask how to include php overwrite settings "I cannot understand" ?? Kindly explain more :D

Answer (score 0):

jupload can upload via ftp

http://jupload.sourceforge.net/

this is an ok solution imo. While not all users enable java, you can make your html page degrade gracefully to http upload, in which case the only users who lose are those who want to upload large files.

or switch webhosts- another easy and effective solution.

Answer (score -1):

You *CAN* use FTP with the "Blueimp Jquery file upload plugin" but it requires some PHP coding. Don't hack up the `UploadHandler` class (file-uploads/server/php/UploadHandler.php), instead you should extend it and override the functions as needed.

Replace the contents of file-uploads/server/php/index.php with the following:

```
require('UploadHandler.php');

/*
 *  custom class for uploading files, simply extends the UploadHander class
 */
class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {


    /*
     * rewreite the handle_file_upload() function to use FTP to send the files to the FTP server
     */
    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index, $content_range);
        $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)$size);
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
            if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
            }
            $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
            $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
                $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
                if ($this->is_valid_image_file($file_path)) {
                    $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
                }
            } else {
                $file->size = $file_size;
                if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                    unlink($file_path);
                    $file->error = $this->get_error_message('abort');
                }
            }
            $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
        }

        /* 
         * now send it to the FTPserver
         */
        $source_file = $file_path; // the path of the file to upload
        $destination_file = '/your/path/' . $file->name; // the file path to upload to (must have trailing / in the path before the $file->name is appended)

        $ftp_error = $this->ftp_upload($source_file, $destination_file);

        if ($ftp_error != '') {
          $file->error = $ftp_error;
        }

        return $file;
    }


    /*
     * new function for uploading using FTP
     */
    protected function ftp_upload($source_file, $destination_file) {

        $ftp_server = 'YOUR FTP HOST NAME';
        $ftp_user_name = 'YOUR USER NAME';
        $ftp_user_pass = 'YOUR PASSWORD';
        $port_number = YOUR FTP PORT NUMBER;

        $error = '';

        // set up basic connection
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $port_number); 
        if (!$conn_id) {
            $error = "FTP connection has failed! Connection attempt was blocked." ;
            return $error;
        }

        // login with username and password
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

        // check connection
        if (!$login_result) { 
            $error = "FTP connection has failed! ";
            $error .= "Could not log into fpt://$ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
            return $error;
        }

        // upload the file
        $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

        // check upload status
        if (!$upload) { 
            $error = "FTP upload has failed!";
        } else {
            $error =  "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
        }

        // close the FTP stream 
        ftp_close($conn_id); 

        return $error;
    }

}

// options to pass to the upload handler object
$options = [
   // ANY OPTIONS, SUCH AS FILE UPLOAD LOCATION
   'upload_url' => 'fpt://YOUR-FTP-SERVER-NAME/files/',
];

// finally, instantiate the new class   
$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);
```

Note that this merely copies the file, via ftp, to the ftp server after it has been uploaded to the upload server. This means you'll have two copies of the same file. You could delete the originally uploaded file without too much extra work, but make sure that the ftp operation has completed first.

You'll need this ***AND*** you'll need the .htaccess apache setting as described by Ohgodwhy